# What is Control ROM and Decision ROM?

Tags: logic, digital-circuits

I have done some research but I cannot answer this question. Please Help.

Comment: Where do these terms come from? This post needs some context.

Comment: I just saw this on one of my studies. 2 ROMS at microcoded cpu...I just got curious cause I do not know the term. But I know ROM is used for writing an operating system. Their addresses are connected with microcounter( a register).

Comment: Read Only Memory (ROM) ?

Answer (score 3):

This terminology is some 30 or more years old coming from the times when Read-only memory (ROM) was a way to implement functions as a cheaper alternative than a general purpose processor. In 1980s hardware many functions would be implemented as ROM modules.

For example, below is a diagram from a 1991 patent US [US5072291](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5072291).

[image: Image quality improvement circuit]

Here one can see different components representing different types of circuits: adders, delay circuits, line memories and ROM circuits. For instance the large upright rectangle at the bottom right part of the image represents an image type detection circuit implemented using ROM technology. This module can be called a Decision ROM.

Nowadays this terminology is rarely used.